# UIImageView animation is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nsarray

I am working on the UIImageView transition in swift. I an storing six images in an array and giving that array to **“imageview.animationImages
”** and I am trying to making it to work as ‘Gif animation’ the code I wrote is as follows :

```
  logoImages = NSMutableArray(array: ["backGround4.jpeg","backGround3.jpeg","backGround.jpeg","16.jpeg","23.jpeg","backGround1.jpeg"])

 imageview.animationImages = NSArray(array:  ["backGround4.jpeg","backGround3.jpeg","backGround.jpeg","16.jpeg","23.jpeg","backGround1.jpeg"]) as? [UIImage]



        imageview.animationDuration = 1.5

        imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1

        imageview.startAnimating()
```

It is not working.Can anyone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing here?
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please convert string to UIImage like this:

```
imageview.animationImages = NSArray(array:  ["backGround4.jpeg","backGround3.jpeg","backGround.jpeg","16.jpeg","23.jpeg","backGround1.jpeg"].map({ (string) -> UIImage in
    UIImage(named: string)! })) as? [UIImage]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

First correct your image name like backGround1.jpeg, backGround2.jpeg etc..

After that create one image array which will hold all your images:

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()
```

Then add all images in image array:

```
for var i = 1; i < totalImageCount; i++ {

    let image = UIImage(named: "backGround4\(i).png")
    imageArray.append(image!)
}
```

After that you can create animation this way:

```
imageview.animationImages = imageArray
imageview.animationDuration = 1.5
imageview.startAnimating()
```

Comment: atal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - is coming at the place of  "imageArray.append(image!)"

Comment: Check your `totalImageCount` and correct it.

Comment: I wrote like this -   for var i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++ {
            
            print(imageArray.count)
            let image = UIImage(named: "backGround4\(i).jpeg")
            imageArray.append(image!)
        }

Comment: Debug you code and you will find the problem.

Comment: Thank you.I found the error and rectified.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
for i in 1...2 {
    images.append(UIImage(named: "c\(i)")!)
}
myImageView.animationImages = images
myImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
myImageView.startAnimating()
```